# Distinct Sums: $f(n) \leq \log_2 n+(1/2)\log_2 (\log_2 n)+O(1)$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

In *The Probabilistic Method*, **Theorem 4.6.1** states that 
$$f(n) \leq \log_2 n+(1/2)\log_2 (\log_2 n)+O(1)$$
where $f(n)$ denotes the maximal $k$ for which there exists a set $\{x_1,\cdots,x_k\}\subset \{1,\cdots,n\}$ with distinct sums.

I have three questions about the "proof", which is presented below:
[image]

How does the inequality on the probability from the first underline: $P(|X-\mu|\geq \lambda n\sqrt{k}/2)\leq 2^{-k}(\lambda n\sqrt{k}+1)$?

Then, shouldn't the optimizing value of $\lambda$ be $2$? I obtained this value from the inequality $n\geq \dfrac{2^k(1-\lambda^{-2})-1}{\sqrt{k}\lambda}$ by finding the zero of the derivative of the right hand expression with respect to $\lambda$.

Finally, I do not understand how the result $f(n) \leq \log_2 n+(1/2)\log_2 (\log_2 n)+O(1)$ from the theorem is obtained from the proof.